# PHP - Return first image in array instead of all?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code to loop through all images in an array which works great, but I want to be able to just return the first image in the array.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php   
    $books = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Images', true );
        foreach( $books as $book){
        $image_id = $book['single_image'];
        echo '<img src="';
        echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id );
        echo '" />';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a numerical array, just get the values from index 0. Like:

```
$books = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Images', true);
$image_id = $books[0]['single_image'];
```